# Cannot remove and then replace rows in a table with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following web page.  It contains a table.  I initially build the table using the default value in the select box.  I want the click event on the button to then remove the rows and replace them with new content from the ajax request.

The html is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<script src = "ajax_ex.js"></script>
<script src = "ajax_ex2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class = "col-md-offset-1"><h1>AJAX EXAMPLE PAGE</h1></div> 

<div class ="row col-md-offset-1">
<select id = "state_select" style = "font-size: 15px">

  <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
  <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
</select>
<input type = "button" class = "btn"
name = "Change_State" value = "Change Table" id ='btn3'/>
</div>


<table class="table-striped col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id = "state_table">
<tr id = "first_row">
<th>Category</th>
<th>2010</th>
<th>2011</th>
<th>2012</th>
<th>2013</th>
<th>2014</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The first JQuery script that builds the table is the following:

```
$(function changestate() {

    var $first_row = $('#first_row')
    var state_filter = $('#state_select').val()

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://opendata.socrata.com/resource/a6x9-fw3a.json?state_name='+ state_filter,
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                $first_row.after('<tr id = "table_row"><td>' + item.measure_category +'</td><td>' + item._2010 +'</td><td>' + item._2011 + '</td><td>' + item._2012 + '</td><td>' + item._2013 + '</td><td>' + item._2014 + '</td></tr>' );
            });
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    //$('#btn3').click(changestate);
})
```

This is the script that I want to run to remove the existing rows and replace them with new rows.  But all that happens is the new rows get appended to the table and it grows.

```
$(function replace_table() {
    var $table_row = $('#table_row')
    var state_filter = $('#state_select').val()
    var $first_row = $('#first_row')

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://opendata.socrata.com/resource/a6x9-fw3a.json?state_name='+ state_filter,
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                $table_row.remove();
                $first_row.after('<tr id = "table_row"><td>' + item.measure_category +'</td><td>' + item._2010 +'</td><td>' + item._2011 + '</td><td>' + item._2012 + '</td><td>' + item._2013 + '</td><td>' + item._2014 + '</td></tr>' );
            })
                console.log(data);
        }
    });
    $('#btn3').click(replace_table);

})
```

I need to do a remove and then replace.

Comment: ID should be unique within the document. Use `class="table_row"` instead. An ID selector - `$('#table_row')` - will always yield zero or one element; `$table_row` will never be several rows.

Comment: `$(function changestate() ...)` doesn't define a function named `changestate`. You need to write `$(function() { function changestate() ... });`

Comment: Every time you call `replace_table`, it adds another click handler to `#btn3`. So if you click on the button 3 times, the next click will call `replace_table` 3 times in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the user pointed out in comments that you should use class name as selector to remove rows from tables instead of the id i.e.

use `$('.table_row').remove();` instead of `$('#table_row').remove();`

and also put this line before

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
```

statement like this

```
$('.table_row').remove();
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
```

so no the changed and working code is

```
$(function changestate() {

    var $first_row = $('#first_row')
    var state_filter = $('#state_select').val()

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://opendata.socrata.com/resource/a6x9-fw3a.json?state_name=' + state_filter,
        success: function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(i, item){
              $first_row.after('<tr class = "table_row"><td>' + item.measure_category + '</td><td>' + item._2010 + '</td><td>' + item._2011 + '</td><td>' + item._2012 + '</td><td>' + item._2013 + '</td><td>' + item._2014 + '</td></tr>');
         });
         console.log('default data = '+JSON.stringify(data));
       };
    });
    //$('#btn3').click(changestate);
});

function replace_table() {
  //var $table_row = $('.table_row')
  var state_filter = $('#state_select').val()
  var $first_row = $('#first_row')

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://opendata.socrata.com/resource/a6x9-fw3a.json?state_name=' + state_filter,
    success: function(data) {
      $('.table_row').remove();
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $first_row.after('<tr class = "table_row"><td>' + item.measure_category + '</td><td>' + item._2010 + '</td><td>' + item._2011 + '</td><td>' + item._2012 + '</td><td>' + item._2013 + '</td><td>' + item._2014 + '</td></tr>');
      });
      console.log('ajax data = '+JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });

}

$('#btn3').click(replace_table);
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xe499yy0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use  .empty function from jQuery to clear all from table. And use tbody in html to clear just that part and append new one.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    table_body = jQuery("#mytable tbody");

  jQuery('button').click(function() {
    //Clear entire table body, leave header as is
    table_body.empty();

    table_body.append('<tr>');
    table_body.append('<td>Appended row</td>');
    table_body.append('<td>Appended row</td>');
    table_body.append('<td>Appended row</td>');
    table_body.append('</tr>');
  });
});
```

Full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/3tabquw3/